# Linq sum by variable number of monthS or weekS

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

SqlServer table contains records of time and hours burned, materials cost by vendors

- [IdPK] [DateTime] [MaterialsCost] [Hours] [Vendor_FK] [Project_FK] [Lat] [Long]

**The user *decides* how far back he wants to see totals** *and* **for which column value**, i.e. he wants totals going back - X number of monthS, *or* X number of weekS on any columns_FK filter value.

For e.g. he wants totals for cost, hours on either, *Vendor = Nike* or ProjectX, going back (1) month, (3) weeks, or 2 months from a certain date. So, I'm trying to get the totals for based on a parameterized Linq query.

**Question**:

1. Using any of columns as a filter/selector in linq, **how to get the Monthly/weekly totals for cost,hours** - going back (X) number of month**s** or week**s**?
2. Also, should I write separate queries for months vs weeks, and separate queries for each column (columns value selected by the user, is passed to me as a genric val)?

   ```
    // I tried this... but just stuck
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    Int goBack = passedinGoingBack;  // amount of units to go back
    var backUnits = obj.GetType().GetProperty(name); // tried getting month or week??
    var getRows = table.AsEnumerable()
    var columnName = passedInColumnName;
    var filter = passedInValue;

   .Where(r =>  r.Field<DateTime>(columnName).Year  == now.Year
             && r.Field<DateTime>(columnName).Month == now.Month);
   ```

Answer (score 5):

This question is a little bit opinion-based. You can do it in any way it is convenient for you. That's how I would do this.

*First*: you can use `Sum` LINQ function for getting total according to the given summing rule.

```
var monthlyRows = table.AsEnumerable()
           .Where(r => r.Field<DateTime>("ColumnName").Year == now.Year 
                    && r.Field<DateTime>("ColumnName").Month == now.Month);

var monthlyTotalForCost = monthlyRows.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("CostColumn"));
var monthlyTotalForHours = monthlyRows.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("HoursColumn"));

var weeklyRows = table.AsEnumerable()
           .Where(r => r.Field<DateTime>("ColumnName").Year == now.Year 
                    && r.Field<DateTime>("ColumnName").Week == now.Week);

var weeklyTotalForCost = monthlyRows.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("CostColumn"));
var weeklyTotalForHours = monthlyRows.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("HoursColumn"));
```

*Second*: I would do separate queries for weekly and monthly totals as that' a sum of different entity values and there can be a different logic.

However, I would do a helping function for me like this:

```
public static class TableLinqHelper
{
    public static SumOfTableColumn<T>(this IEnumerable<DataRow> rows, string columnName)
    {
        return rows.Sum(r => r.Field<T>(columnName));
    }

    public static DateTime GetDate(this DataRow row)
    {
        return row.Field<DateTime>("DateColumn");
    }

    public static GetTotalForCost(this IEnumerable<DataRow> row)
    {
        return SumOfTableColumn<decimal>(row, "CostColumn");
    }

    public static GetTotalForHours(this IEnumerable<DataRow> row)
    {
        return SumOfTableColumn<double>(row, "HoursColumn");
    }
}

var monthlyRows = table.AsEnumerable()
           .Where(r => r.GetTime().Year == now.Year 
                    && r.GetTime().Month == now.Month);
var weeklyRows = table.AsEnumerable()
           .Where(r => r.GetTime().Year == now.Year 
                    && r.GetTime().Week == now.Week);


var monthlyTotalForCost = monthlyRows.GetTotalForCost();
var monthlyTotalForHours = monthlyRows.GetTotalForHours();
var weeklyTotalForCost = weeklyRows.GetTotalForCost();
var weeklyTotalForHours = weeklyRows.GetTotalForHours();
```

**Update:**

**Filtering:** You can filter your results using `Where` LINQ.

```
Dictionary<string, object> Filters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
Filters.Add("VendorColumn", "Nike");
Filters.Add("Hours", 7.0);

foreach (var filter in Filters)
{
   monthlyRows = monthlyRows.Where(r => // ...);
}
```

**Several monthes and weeks:** You can change the condition of DateTime where.

```
int rowsToBeShown = 4;
var monthlyRows = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<DateTime>("ColumnName") > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-rowsToBeShown));
```

It will show results for the last 4 monthes.

LINQ provides very convenient and flexible tools for data manipulation. It's all up to your fantasy.

Comment: thanks for the response, can you please see, it is returning the sum for the entire column and _not filtered on Vendor = Nike_. It also _does not calculate the months going back_... for e.g. user wants totals for Vendor Nike for last (2 or 3 or X) months

Comment: I'm trying to test it. So, if I understand _Step 1_ `var monthlyRows = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<DateTime>("ColumnName") > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-rowsToBeShown));` will I get all rows for last 4 months _based on the actual month strarting dates_ or _4 months back from today, i.e. 120 days back from june 13_ ? Then next _step 2_ are you saying I can perform the filters on `monthlyRows` table? Then _Step 3_  sum the values `SumOfTableColumn<T>( rows, string columnName) // the table as rows?` ?    How do I call this, can you please show me example, for _step 2 and step 3_

Comment: What about addWeeks, how do I go back weekS (using Sunday based weeks)? Should I just add days offset from the first sunday?